# Regular expression, back reference or alternate construct

Tags: .net, regex, recursive-regex

I am trying to write a regular expression in .NET to capture the whole function from a list of functions that look something like this.

```
public string Test1()
{
    string result = null;
    foreach(var item in Entity.EntityProperties)
    {
        result +=string.Format("inner string with bracket{0}", "test");
    }
    return result;
}
public string Test5()
{
    return string.Format("inner string with bracket{0}", "test");
}

public string Last()
{
    return string.Format("inner string with bracket{0}", "test");
}
```

So I got

```
((?<function>public string (?<fName>\w+)\(\)\s*{.*?})(?=\s*public string))
```

This will capture all but the last function... or this

```
((?<function>public string (?<fName>\w+)\(\)\s*{.*?})(?=\s*(public string)|$))
```

This will match all functions correctly except the first one. The first function is only matched partially.

```
public string Test1()
{
    string result = null;
    foreach(var item in Entity.EntityProperties)
    {
        result +=string.Format("inner string with bracket{0}", "test");
    } <-- the first capture only get to this point.
```

Any idea? Please provide some explanation if possible.

Comment: Guess what? Regexes don't handle arbitrarily nested braces very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually possible to do it in .NET to check for matching bracket. The key is to use a balancing group. I've heard of it before that's why I ask the question. I just wasn't sure how to write the expression myself so I was hoping that some of the resident reg expert could help me out :)

Luckily I found this website. Which explain balancing group in details... he even provide a template. So here it is for everyone else reference.

http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/balancing-groups
the gist of the pattern is here

```
{
    (?>
        (?! { | } ) .
    |
        { (?<Depth>)
    |
        } (?<-Depth>)
    )*
    (?(Depth)(?!))
}
```

but check out his blog for the details explanation.

Comment: You might have gotten better results if you had said what you were trying to do in your question's title.

Comment: You are right, what do you think about a title like this?
I need a regular expression to capture a function body in c# source code?

Answer (score 1):

Although I like regexes a lot, in your case they won't work because nested structures are not "regular" and therefore can't be matched with regular expressions. You need a parser for this kind of job. Sorry.